# Frame can't show different params in each Tab items

Tags: android, xml, nativescript, frame, tabview

I use Nativescript for my app but I found some problem. I create TabView and I add Frame on each of Tab items. Then I use Frame to call a page for showing and I send different params to each Frame too. But when Frame showing, it was show latest params that I send only

ex. **expect**

TabItem1 -> Frame --(param1)--> showing param1

TabItem2 -> Frame --(param2)--> showing param2

TabItem3 -> Frame --(param3)--> showing param3

ex. **response**

TabItem1 -> Frame --(param1)--> showing param3

TabItem2 -> Frame --(param2)--> showing param3

TabItem3 -> Frame --(param3)--> showing param3

maybe it because I use defaultPage on Frame same all
question is how I can send params and Frame can show params that I send like as I expect.

Answer (score 0):

you should add a unique `id` to each `Frame`.

If you use vue: https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/routing/manual-routing/#navigating-within-a-frame

without vue: https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/navigation#frame